# How to import from __future__ in C extension module

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I've got an extension module that needs to support Python 2 and Python 3.  When it loads, I want to do something like `from __future__ import print_function` so that if anyone tries to do this:

```
PyRun_SimpleString("print 'foo'");
```

it will fail, but if they do this:

```
PyRun_SimpleString("print('foo', file=sys.stdout)");
```

it will succeed.  I've tried a number of things, including `PyRun_SimpleString` of the from future statement.  like this:

```
PyRun_SimpleString("from __future__ import print_function");
```

and I've also tried calling `PyImport_ImportModuleEx` like this:

```
PyImport_ImportModuleEx("__future__", nullptr, nullptr, fromlist);
```

where `fromlist` is a `PyObject` representing the list `["print_function"]`

Neither of these works.  Is it possible to make this work?

Comment: Why is your extension module using `PyRun_SimpleString`, especially to print things?

Comment: It's not exactly, this is for the sake of illustrating the problem.  It does, however, expose an embedded interpreter.  i.e. you can perform some actions within the program to drop to a python prompt, or you can run some commands that execute python code and display the interpreter's output (those commands are passed through via `PyRun_SimpleString`.  What I need is a way to disable print statements so that if anyone runs a print statement, they will get an error.

Comment: That's a pretty different problem from the one you're asking about, and the solution is pretty different.

Comment: Umm, ok?  I'm not sure I follow.  The commands users are entering get passed through to `PyRun_SimpleString`.  Therefore by making sure that `PyRun_SimpleString("print 'foo'")` generates an error, I also make sure that it generates an error when they enter that command.  Which is the problem I am trying to solve.  It might help me to understand what you're getting at if you were a little bit less ambiguous in your statements.

Comment: The question you've asked is about getting the effects of future statements in calls to `PyRun_SimpleString`, while the problem you're actually trying to solve is running user-provided Python code under the effects of future statements. `PyRun_SimpleString` isn't the tool for the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyRun_SimpleString doesn't have anywhere to specify compiler flags, but there's a [whole host of related functions](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html) with more options available. For example, `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags` does what `PyRun_SimpleString` does, but with a `flags` argument to specify compiler flags. `__future__` statements executed with `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags` can modify the `flags`, and the change will be seen by other calls using the same `flags`.

You can initialize `flags` with future statements, or with the C-level flag definitions. Most of the possible flags aren't listed in the C-api documentation (since the C-api documentation kind of sucks), but you can find them in the `__future__` module or in several parts of the Python source code.

```
>>> import __future__
>>> for name in dir(__future__):
...     if name.startswith('CO_'):
...         print name
...
CO_FUTURE_ABSOLUTE_IMPORT
CO_FUTURE_DIVISION
CO_FUTURE_PRINT_FUNCTION
CO_FUTURE_UNICODE_LITERALS
CO_FUTURE_WITH_STATEMENT
CO_GENERATOR_ALLOWED
CO_NESTED
```

For example, you could run a string under the effects of `from __future__ import print_function` with

```
PyCompilerFlags flags = {CO_FUTURE_PRINT_FUNCTION};
PyRun_SimpleStringFlags(command, &flags);
```

If you want to save the effects of user-executed future statements, you'd save the PyCompilerFlags struct somewhere and use the same one for all calls.

---

With that said, I don't think automatically applying `from __future__ import print_function` is the right thing to do. It'll surprise people expecting the default behavior of whatever interpreter they're on. Also, `PyRun_InteractiveOneFlags` might be useful for letting the user input multi-line Python statements.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.  Is there any way to get the set of flags the interpreter is currently under the effects of?  This way I could get that set of flags, and add in `CO_FUTURE_PRINT_FUNCTION`.  This is in an extension module that has to support both Py2 and Py3 with a single codebase and -- in particular -- a single set of tests.  So mandating print function is the best way (that I know of) to ensure that the test suite always passes all the time.

Comment: @ZacharyTurner: I don't think that's something the interpreter exposes. I did figure out how to preserve flags from one statement to the next, though. As for the test suite, if you preserve user-executed future statements, you can just put `from __future__ import print_function` in your test setup.